# Unable to modify colorbox settings on onload trigger

Tags: jquery, colorbox

I am trying to override default colorbox parameter withing onLoad event trigger:

```
 $(".iframe").colorbox  ({
    iframe:true,
    width: '80%',
    height: '80%',
    onLoad:function() {

        $.colorbox.settings = '40%';

    }
});
```

But colorbox does not use that setting, debuger shows that after event has been triggered - it used the initial setting and my modification appears to be some kind of default parameters copy. Calculations for width ignore my new setting and the initial value is being used...

How do I access settings properties of the colorbox object I am currently working with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've checked the sources at http://www.jacklmoore.com/colorbox/jquery.colorbox.js and managed to hack this together:

```
$(".iframe").colorbox  ({
    iframe:true,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
    onLoad:function() {

        var d = $(this).data('colorbox');
        d.width = '20%';
        $(this).data('colorbox',d);
    }
});
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, thanks, but cb is undefined? changing cb to d, didnt help either... do you have a jsfiddle example working?

Comment: @Ulterior corrected. It's `d` instead of `cb`, sorry for that.

Comment: looks like it should work, but no effect. maybe my version is too low? I am using jQuery Colorbox v1.4.21 - 2013-06-06

Comment: It works on 1.5.4. Can you upload your version to pastebin or somewhere else?

Comment: yes, the problem was in my old version, thanks, you are the best ;)

Comment: Can you clarify $(this) element inside onLoad event as I am getting error d is undefined? Which element should be $(this) here?

Comment: @sumanchalki `$(this)` should be an individual `class="iframe"` element. So basically selector returns a collection on which we're initializing the colorbox plugin.